# Can you change the combined center of gravity (COG) of the rider and bike if you move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, friction

In a closed system, I know the rider wouldn't be able to change the combined center of gravity of the system by moving his weight around. If he pushes the bike to lean to the right, he would go to the left by the amount that would keep the combined cog the same.

But a bike with tires and a road under it is not a closed system, the tires wouldn't let the lower part of the bike left or right when tryingo to initiate lean. Does this mean it is possible to push with your bodies inertia to the bike, and the combined cog will be changed? I thing if you do so above the cog of the bike, you could, but I am not sure.

Edit: My question is not about if you can move the center of gravity of the bike at all. My question is about if can you change the combine cog of the system by moving around on the bike?

English is not my mother tongue, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The center of gravity (c.o.g.), or center of mass (CM), (you should spell it out the first time you  say it if you want to use an acronym to avoid confusion) moves all the time.  I don't really understand why you're asking a question.

Comment: Editted so my question is more clear, sorry for my mistakes, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a circular movement with your bike (imagine a circular track) you don't stay totally vertical, but the system bike-body is inclined with certain angle, as in the photo below.

[image]

This is because you have to equilibrate centrifugal force with gravitational force, and this is done by changing the position of the center of mass of the system bike-body. Note that if there's no friction, you cannot turn in curves, so centrifugal force doesn't appear.

Edit: As you say in the question, due to friction the system is non conservative. This means that momentum (and energy) is not conserved, so if you move around on the bike then the combined center of mass won't hold its position.

Comment: Please check the original post again, I tried to explain it better. Thank you

Comment: Edited the original post so the question is clear, sorry. Engliah is not my mother tongue, can you answer it please?

Comment: In the answer I refer to the combined center of gravity. When I say "system bike-body" I mean the total system formed by the bike and the rider. English also is not my mother tongue... However, I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I was asking if you can change the combined center of gravity of the system by moving your body on the bike, and produce a net torque

Comment: If you center of gravity stays totally on the vertical there's no torque due to gravity because the $r$ vector and gravity force are parallel. If you change the position of the total center of gravity so they are no longer parallel, then this will cause a net torque. Imagine you and your bike are at rest. If you want to stay vertical, you will move your body around to avoid falling to the ground. What you are really doing is change continuously the position of the center of gravity, so you are producing torques which tend to maintain you onto the bike.

Comment: Yes but how would the combined cog of the system despite the consertvation of momentum in a closed system? Is it because there is friction between tires and the road so it isnt really a closed system?

Comment: You are right. The system is non-conservative due to friction. This means that momentum (and energy) is not conserved, so you can change the position of the center of gravity. I may edit the answer when I have a moment.

Comment: Can you please, when you have time?